# Will developing for PHP 5.3 break compatibility with shared hosts?

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I'm thinking of developing a project of mine using PHP 5.3 features like anonymous functions and namespaces, but I'm affraid some shared hosts out there won't support it and people who download my software won't be able to use it.

Should I be concerned or go ahead and do it?

Comment: I don't think anybody can answer this for you.. I mean, do you even have an idea of how many of your clients will fall in this group? Personally, I don't think it's unreasonable to require 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will break BC with some hosts. Do it anyway. Those host have no reason to upgrade until their users complain because things no longer work.

This is my opinion, nothing more.